# Why do these two hex numbers come up at the same integer on online calcs?

Tags: c#, hex

This is really annoying, I have two hex numbers I am 90% sure that one of them is exactly 2 increment higher. However when I type them into an online hex to decimal calculator they come out the same. How can this be?

```
lower number at
0x00010471000001BF001F = 18766781122258862000

higher number at
0x00010471000001BF0021 = 18766781122258862000
```

? What is going on ?

The calc I used is...
http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.htm

Comment: One higher? 1F + 1 = 20, not 21...

Answer (score 2):

The higher number is 2 higher instead of 1. 0x00010471000001BF0020 is in between. I think your problem is related to an overflow issue because the numbers are very large. Probably the calculators you are using are converting the values to floating point which looses accuracy.

The values you are posting need at least 9 bytes to represent (or at least 65 bits)

Answer (score 0):

First basic knowledge of Hex should tell you that 20 is between 1F and 21, so the highest number is the lower number + 2.
Second, if you use an unknown tool, you have to be sure it's reliable. Your tool obviously can't handle such large numbers.
Wolfram Alpha gives you the correct answers :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x00010471000001BF001F+in+decimal
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x00010471000001BF0021+in+decimal

Comment: Ksempac this was just a a typo.

Comment: First I couldn't know that, and Second I didn't post that only to point the mistake out, I gave you the correct answer (and how to solve similar problems in the future, Wolfram Alpha is dedicated to scientific queries)...

Answer (score 0):

First things first, why did you classify this question under the C# tag?
The problem is most like caused by the value being too big and the converter doesn't work well with big numbers.

Just because this is tagged with C#.
Add a reference to .NET component System.Numerics.
To convert from large hex to integer use BigInteger.

```
        System.Numerics.BigInteger a;
        System.Numerics.BigInteger.TryParse("00010471000001BF001F", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber,null,out a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        System.Numerics.BigInteger.TryParse("00010471000001BF0021", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
```

output

```
18766781122258862111
18766781122258862113
```